# Performance optimization on Django update or create

Tags: django, optimization

In a Django project, I'm refreshing tens of thousands of lines of data from an external API on a daily basis.  The problem is that since I don't know if the data is new or just an update, I can't do a `bulk_create` operation.

**Note**: Some, or perhaps many, of the rows, do not actually change on a daily basis, but I don't which, or how many, ahead of time.

So for now I do:

```
for row in csv_data:
    try:
        MyModel.objects.update_or_create(id=row['id'], defaults={'field1': row['value1']....})
    except:
        print 'error!'
```

And it takes.... forever!  One or two lines a second, max speed, sometimes several seconds per line.  Each model I'm refreshing has one or more other models connected to it through a foreign key, so I can't just delete them all and reinsert every day.  I can't wrap my head around this one -- how can I cut down significantly the number of database operations so the refresh doesn't take hours and hours.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are starting to get into the limits of django ORM. This type of optimisation should move to the database: start with indexes that index the main fields you query, slow query logs, etc. The first step is usually a narrow index: a table with only the index (so many rows as possible are saved in a single DB page). You search this index table, which you should optimise. Then, based on what you find, you start working on the real data table.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really follow how this can cut down the update time?

Comment: Updating one record takes one second? That's really slow. What database are you using? What kind of server do you have?

Comment: @ShangWang At the moment the times I'm seeing are from me running the django server locally, and the database is a postgres hosted by compose.io.  I'm sure times will be somewhat faster from the server, but I need it be, like, 10 times faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you are doing a database action on each data row you grabbed from the api. You can avoid doing that by understanding which of the rows are new (and do a bulk insert to all new rows), Which of the rows actually need update, and which didn't change.
To elaborate:

1. grab all the relevant rows from the database (meaning all the rows that can possibly be updated)

```
old_data = MyModel.objects.all() # if possible than do MyModel.objects.filter(...)
```

2. Grab all the api data you need to insert or update

```
api_data = [...]
```

3. for each row of data understand if its new and put it in array, or determine if the row needs to update the DB

```
    for row in api_data:
        if is_new_row(row, old_data):
            new_rows_array.append(row)
        else:
            if is_data_modified(row, old_data):
                ...
                # do the update
            else:
                continue
     MyModel.objects.bulk_create(new_rows_array)
```

`is_new_row` - will understand if the row is new and add it to an array that will be bulk created

`is_data_modified` - will look for the row in the old data and understand if the data of that row is changed and will update only if its changed

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. I'll try it out today and see what happens.

Comment: I took your advice and pulled all the relevant records out of the db, compared them with fast python methods, and only updated the ones that had changed.  It cut down the whole download process from many hours to about an hour at most!  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Couldn't this possible lead to a race condition? I mean: you grab all the existing rows from the database and check if the data received from the api does already exists. What if another user in the meantime deletes or inserts a new entry? Wouldn't the use of raw sql queries like "INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" if using mysql/mariadb, be a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [the source code for update_or_create()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/bdbe50a491ca41e7d4ebace47bfe8abe50a58211/django/db/models/query.py#L469), you'll see that it's hitting the database multiple times for each call (either a `get()` followed by a `save()`, or a `get()` followed by a `create()`). It does things this way to maximize internal consistency - for example, this ensures that your model's `save()` method is called in either case.

But you might well be able to do better, depending on your specific models and the nature of your data. For example, if you don't have a custom `save()` method, aren't relying on signals, and know that most of your incoming data maps to existing rows, you could instead try an `update()` followed by a `bulk_create()` if the row doesn't exist. Leaving aside related models, that would result in one query in most cases, and two queries at the most. Something like:

```
updated = MyModel.objects.filter(field1="stuff").update(field2="other")
if not updated:
    MyModel.objects.bulk_create([MyModel(field1="stuff", field2="other")])
```

(Note that this simplified example has a race condition, see the Django source for how to deal with it.)

In the future there will [probably be support for PostgreSQL's UPSERT functionality](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/swBPqFi-Tdk), but of course that won't help you now.

Finally, as mentioned in the comment above, the slowness might just be a function of your database structure and not anything Django-specific.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I was looking for something __much__ more efficient, not just a little.

Comment: Plus, this isn't feasible at all. I can't be doing bulk updates, since each row has distinct values...

Comment: @jegesh: The example I gave isn't doing a bulk update - it's using `bulk_create()` to insert a single record. I did it that way for consistency with `update` (e.g. neither one generates signals).

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the accepted answer. One way of recognizing whether the operation is an update or create is to ask the api owner to include a last updated timestamp with each row (if possible) and store it in your db for each row. That way you only have to check for those rows where this timestamp is different from the one in api.

I faced an exact issue where I was updating every existing row and creating new ones. It took a whole minute to update 8000 odd rows. With selective updates, I cut down my time to just 10-15 seconds depending on how many rows have actually changed.

Answer (score -2):

I think below code can do the same thing together instead of `update_or_create`:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(...).update()
MyModel.objects.get_or_create()
```